# Issue with zooming/scaling CClayer (cocos2d + box2d)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

im making angry bird like game in `cocos2d & box2d` for Iphone, in which i need to zoom out my camera view as my thrown body goes out of screen and later on it should be zoom in as per normal position.(if u have played angry bird in mobiles i hope u got what im exactly stucked into) i'v tried to scale my whole layer but not worked as per need.can i use camera of `cocos2d` to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use scale factor.Camera will not zoom in and out, it will only move horizontally and vertically on your scene
Use scale factor in action to go give it animation effect as in angry birds

```
id myAction = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scaleX:2.0 ScaleY:2.0];    
[self runAction:myAction];
```

That should do it!

Comment: thnks, i'v tried this, i think this will meet my expectation by little modification like scale back to normal screen and relating duration and scale factor with my thrown body...

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use the scale factor of the CCLayer.

self.scale = someFactor;

someFactor ranges from 0 to 1.

In order to achieve a cool effect, you could try to change the factor proportionally of the velocity of your sprite. I recommend that you use a schedule to change the scale over time.

Comment: what would be great? , to use static value for scale factor to cover maximum screen or by relating it with my body??